# Table row throws NullPointerException when creating multiple rows in Android

Tags: java, android

My table is created by taking data from Firebase realtime database, I have added ValueEventListener so my table is recreate whenever data is changed in database, my table works fine when one or two data is added in database simultaneously but it throws exception when 3 or more data is added to database simultaneously.

Code

```
rollNoQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    int rollNo;
    String firstname, lastname;

    table.removeViews(1, table.getChildCount() - 1);
    for (DataSnapshot dsp : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        rollNo = dsp.child("rollNo").getValue(Integer.class);
        firstname = dsp.child("firstname").getValue(String.class);
        lastname = dsp.child("lastname").getValue(String.class);

        createTableRow(rollNo, firstname + " " + lastname);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    progressDialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Code of createTableRow

```
private void createTableRow(int rollNo, String name) {
TableRow tbRow = new TableRow(getContext());

tbRow.setTag(rollNo);

TextView tv0 = new TextView(getContext());
TextView tv1 = new TextView(getContext());
TextView tv2 = new TextView(getContext());

tv0.setText(String.valueOf(rollNo));
tv1.setText(name);
tv2.setText("✅");

tv0.setTextSize(16);
tv1.setTextSize(16);
tv2.setTextSize(16);

tv0.setPadding(30, 30, 15, 30);
tv1.setPadding(30, 30, 15, 30);
tv2.setPadding(30, 30, 15, 30);

tv0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

tv0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);
tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);
tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);

tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

if (isFirstRow) {
    tv0.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    tv1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    isFirstRow = false;
} else {
    tv0.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
    tv1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
    isFirstRow = true;
}

tbRow.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        return true;
    }
});

tbRow.addView(tv0);
tbRow.addView(tv1);
tbRow.addView(tv2);

table.addView(tbRow);
}
```

Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method    'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:432)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4573)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4706)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:234)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:230)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:226)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:222)
    at android.widget.TableRow.<init>(TableRow.java:60)
    at com.suyogbauskar.attenteachers.fragments.AttendanceFragment.createTableRow(AttendanceFragment.java:206)
    at com.suyogbauskar.attenteachers.fragments.AttendanceFragment.access$600(AttendanceFragment.java:36)
    at com.suyogbauskar.attenteachers.fragments.AttendanceFragment$1$1$1.onDataChange(AttendanceFragment.java:132)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Or is there any other approach to create table dynamically using ValueEventListener(Firebase Realtime database)

Comment: On this class `ViewConfiguration`, go to line 432. You will find your issue there.

Comment: I don't have class `ViewConfiguration`

Comment: Trace it back until you find where you made the mistake. The stack trace is telling you where the problem is.

Comment: The async callback seems to fire when the fragment is not attached and `getContext()` returns null.

Comment: @laalto I don't think this can happen because my fragment remains in foreground while rows are made

Comment: Anyway the stacktrace suggests that a null is passed as a context to a view constructor.

Comment: Your problem is actually unsuccessful resource access. There is problem with the reference of `Context` object in which you implement `createTableRow()` function. Can you post the whole activity or fragment code where you implement `createTableRow()`? Because this exception is raised  when you call `getResources()`. `AttendanceFragment.java:206` This is where you need to seek the error, somethings happen when the flow reaches here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
requireContext();
```

if your in a fragment.  If your desperate, try:

```
requireActivity();
```

Good luck.

Comment: After using `requireContext();` I am getting this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment AttendanceFragment{7b29da8} (b5be35cb-ff96-4a83-b72c-af3358563b38) not attached to a context.`

Comment: After using `requireActivity();` I am getting this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment AttendanceFragment{6c0c93f} (552b590f-a0c8-466d-ad81-02b1626c4506) not attached to an activity.`

Comment: Wow.  Is your fragment being added the old fashioned way, or is it part of some navigation system?  My assumption is that your context via getContext() is NULL, which it should be.  To insure Context, try overriding your onAttach() method that comes along with the Fragment class.  You can pull out the passed Context variable and use it within your scope.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am changing fragments using bottom navigation, I used context from `onAttach()` but it is also generating exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Can you confirm that context is NULL with a simple log for me?  To keep me from vomitting.

Comment: after logging context I am getting null `D/FadeMove: Context: null`, Don't know why context is null

Comment: Try typecasting your Activity for context.  I.e. MainActivity mainActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());  Then try using mainActivity as context. Obviously replace MainActivity with the activity that is the "root" of the fragment.

Comment: After type casting Activity my table was creating fine but after 2 seconds other exception was thrown, So I converted that fragment to activity and now its working fine, Thank you